# How do I put keys to values in my jsonarray and make them into objects?

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have a JSON array `jsonMatchingContacts` like this:

```
["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", etc...]
```

I am trying to make it like this:

```
[{"key":"value1"}, {"key":"value2"}, {"key":"value3"}, {"key":"value4"}, etc...]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
    for (int i =0; i<jsonMatchingContacts.length() ; i++) {
        JSONObject newobject = new JSONObject();
        newobject.put("phone_number", (what goes here?));
        etc...
    }
```

I've tried a lot of different things with the help of this site but it's not working the way I need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (int i =0; i<jsonMatchingContacts.length() ; i++) {
        JSONObject newobject = new JSONObject();
        newobject.put("phone_number", jsonMatchingContacts.getString(i));

    }
```

The above is for the `object`. And then to convert it to a `JSON Array` again:

```
    JSONArray newarray = new JSONArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonMatchingContacts.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject newobject = new JSONObject();
        newobject.put("phone_number", jsonMatchingContacts.getString(i));

        newarray.put(newobject);

    }
```